# Value Error while applying conditions to a loop (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, conditional-statements

```
while (i< len(df)):
    if (df['ID'][i] == df['ID'][i+1]) & (df['Week_start'] == df['Week_end']):
        if (df['ship'][i]  > df['ship'][i+1] ):
            df['radar'][i] =df['radar'][i+1] + df['parked'][i] - df['parked'][i+1]
        else:
            df['radar'][i] =df['radar'][i+1]
    else:
        df['radar'][i] = df['ship'][i]
    i = i+1
```

I tried to get this code running but I keep on getting an error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

What do you recommend? Essentially I want to fill up the column radar based on conditions, I think the rest but that part work.

Comment: Add sample data, expected output and logic behind your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error in this line:

```py
df['Week_start'] == df['Week_end']
```

specify some index like

```
df['Week_start'][i]== df['Week_end'][i+1]
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I get this error: C:\Users\user\Documents\AnacondaNewFolder\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:41: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
C:\Users\user\Documents\AnacondaNewFolder\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:39: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame